# Thinkpad X250 to X260 back cover compatibility?

Tags: laptop, wireless, displays

I have to fix a Thinkpad X250 back cover that's cracked. I have on hand a X260 back cover, but would have to order one for the X250.

From various product pages I see hints that X240/X250 use the same exact back cover, while the X260 is not mentioned.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back cover is quite vague. The LCD back cover? It isn't compatible:
[image: x250][image: X260]

The antenna placement isn't the same. Also, the hinge isn't the correct type.

If you are talking about the back (bottom cover), it isn't compatible either:
[image][image]

The USB ports are not all at the same location.

Comment: Yes, it looks incompatible. I will need the 04X5359. I am talking about the lid cover on an X250.